# How i can change JButton size in java?

Tags: java

I am learning java GUI programming and I would like to create button. Problem is when button is created it is huge. How I can resize button?

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Ikkuna <3");

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JLabel teksti = new JLabel("assdad", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    teksti.setFont(new Font("Eras Demi ITC", Font.PLAIN, 32));
    teksti.setForeground(Color.BLUE);//tekstin väri
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/account/Documents/NetBeansProjects/eka/src/eka/Kuvat/Trollface.PNG"); //Tämä on kuvake(icon). 
    frame.setIconImage(img.getImage());

    JButton nappula = new JButton("Start");
    frame.getContentPane().add(nappula);
    nappula.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(83, 291));
    nappula.setLocation(500, 350);

    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    teksti.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));

    frame.getContentPane().add(teksti, BorderLayout.PAGE_START); 
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);                          
    
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

I also tried this:

`nappula.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(83, 291));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can set the fonts to the button and change its size

```
Font f = new Font("Times New Roman",Font.BOLD,20);
nappula.setFont(f);
```

Set it of any size change 20 to any value......
Try it....

Comment: try using setBounds() Function it has location and sets dimentions of the button  setBounds(x-location,y-location,x-size,y-size)

Answer (score 0):

You're using default layout from the looks of it. Try using

```
nappula.setSize(new Dimension(x, y));
```

Comment: Add the following after the JFrame declaration:
`frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));` and go back to using the preferred size method

Comment: its work but then my label and button go to START_LINE, but i want add my label to START_PAGE  and my button to CENTER, thank you